# Why is the container null for static fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following Layout with static fragment and RelativeLayout as parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
        android:name="com.listfragmenttest.MyListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Yet the container or parent comes up `null` in OnCreateView:

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                                                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Is this the normal behavior for Static fragment?

Comment: What's leading you to believe that either of those is null? Are you getting an Exception? If so, please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: @MikeM.: I am seeing the value `container = null` in Debug.

Comment: That doesn't really tell us much out of context. Are you sure it's related to your code? What ill effects is it causing? Is it crashing? Or causing unexpected behavior? Please post the relevant log output, and a description of what exactly the problem is.

Comment: No, it's not causing any of such effect. I want to confirm if this is the normal behavior for static fragment because in dynamic fragment the value of container was non-null.

Comment: @MikeM.: Shouldn't the RelativeLayout defined in XML be the parent/container for Fragment? In dynamic fragment, you would also need to have a layout defined in XML to act as a parent/container.

Comment: Lemme rephrase that. It makes sense, because static `Fragment`s are handled a little differently than dynamic fragments. A null `container` is passed into `onCreateView()`, then the `View` returned from that is added to the layout in place of the `<fragment>`, at which time the given layout attributes are applied. At least, in my experience. @laalto seems to think otherwise, but I believe I always get a null container. Lemme have a look.

Comment: I feel I may have confused you with my seemingly contradictory comments. I thought you meant you were seeing `container = null` in your logcat, which is why I kept asking you to post that. My apologies. laalto does have the right answer now. It is normal for static `Fragment`s to be passed a null container. I hope I didn't trip you up too much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's how it is implemented. Fragments inflated statically from XML get a `null` as parent container.

For details, consult [`FragmentManager` source](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java). In particular, `onCreateView()` that handles fragment instantiation from layout inflation, setting `mInLayout = true` and calls to `performCreateView()` that are conditional on `mInLayout`.

Comment: Something that could go like `android:id="@+id/frag_RelativeLayout`? I did, but its still null.

Comment: Yes that was only part of the story. Updated the answer after refreshing myself with more source-reading.